# How to enable default on one page after e.preventDefault() in main.js?

Tags: javascript

I searched stackoverflow and there are a few topics about this problem, but not exactly what I am looking for. The wordpress theme I'm using updated recently and now has this in their main.js - collapse data-api:

```
$(document).on('click.bs.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function (e) {
var $this   = $(this), href;
var target  = $this.attr('data-target')
    || e.preventDefault()
    || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, ''); //strip for ie7
var $target = $(target);
var data    = $target.data('bs.collapse');
var option  = data ? 'toggle' : $this.data();
var parent  = $this.attr('data-parent');
var $parent = parent && $(parent);

if (!data || !data.transitioning) {
  if ($parent) $parent.find('[data-toggle=collapse][data-parent="' + parent + '"]').not($this).addClass('collapsed');
  $this[$target.hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed');
}

$target.collapse(option);
});
```

The problem is that the line `e.preventDefault()` is blocking the links in the dropdown menu on the page from open the parts of the content they link to (there are #divs on the page, that would display after clicking - `display:none` --> `display:block;`)

Anyway, my question is - can I enable the default actions for the whole page? I need it only for this particular page, and I can't change the main.js code, because it affects other pages. All of the solutions I found are about putting return true with `onclick`, but I would like to just have a `<script>...</script>` that I could put inside the page content, that would just enable the default actions for this page - like on load or something. If it's even possible or does it have to be connected to an event? I'm sorry, but I'm not a JavaScript programmer, I just need to fix what the update messed up..

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've provided, the `e.preventDefault()` is only hit if the relevant `[data-toggle=collapse]` element has no `data-target` attribute:

```
var target  = $this.attr('data-target')
              || e.preventDefault()
              || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '');
```

What this does is:

1. Attempt to assign the value of `$this.attr('data-target')` to the `target` variable.
2. If no `data-target` attribute exists on the element, set it to the result of calling `e.preventDefault()`.
3. If that failed (which it always will as `e.preventDefault()` doesn't return anything, set it to the element's `href`, replacing a few bits.

The `e.preventDefault()` would not be hit if your element has a `data-target` attribute:

```
<div data-target="..." data-toggle=collapse></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried to assign data-target and data-toggle to my buttons, and they open the content, but the problem is that when you hit the next button/link, it doesn't hide the content the previous button opened.. In order to close it you need to click that same button again. Here is the website: http://stowarzyszeniestop.pl/stop/baza-trenerow/

Comment: And the dropdown menu I assigned the data-target to is on the top right: "Certyfikat".